# How to handle pageobject model with iframes in selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, iframe, ui-automation, pageobjects

Working on a project with java+selenium webdriver + testng
I was wondering what's the best way of handling (if there is one) iframes in the pageobject?

Comment: Taking a look at [this post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/44142/is-the-page-object-pattern-the-ideal-approach-for-browser-automation-for-a-websi) might help you out.

Answer (score 0):

All your existing page object structure remains same. All you have to do is a switch over to the specific iframe before manipulating an object and again switch back to default content after specific operation over that object.